# Django: how to show name as per user_id?

Tags: python, json, sql-server, django, api

```
class Order_ListAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        totalData=[]
        if request.method == 'GET':
            cur,conn = connection()
            order_query = ''' SELECT * FROM orders '''
            order_detail_query = ''' SELECT * FROM order_details '''
            user_query = ''' SELECT * FROM users '''

            with conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:

                cursor.execute(order_detail_query)
                order_detail_result = cursor.fetchall()
                order_detail_data = list(order_detail_result)
                # print(order_detail_data)

                cursor.execute(order_query)
                order_result = cursor.fetchall()
                order_data = list(order_result)

                cursor.execute(user_query)
                user_result = cursor.fetchall()
                user_data = list(user_result)

                dic = {}
                def merge_order_data_and_detail(order_data, order_detail_data):
                    for d in order_detail_data:
                        if d['order_id'] not in dic:
                            dic[d['order_id']] = []
                        dic[d['order_id']].append(d)


                    for o in order_data:
                        if o['order_id'] in dic:
                            o['order_detail_data'] = dic[o['order_id']]

                merge_order_data_and_detail(order_data, order_detail_data)

            # totalData.append({"order_data":order_data, })
            return Response({"order_data":order_data, "user_data":user_data},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "order_data": [
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "payment_method_id": 1,
            "delivery_id": 2,
            "user_id": 3,
            "txnid": "584ffb7fd622eca10a6d",
            "order_no": "1-1583152683-0005",
            "order_total": 1.0,
            "payment_status": "Paid",
            "payuMoneyId": "306043618",
            "mihpayid": "9956109007",
            "order_detail_data": [
                {
                    "order_detail_id": 1,
                    "order_id": 1,
                    "user_id": 3,
                    "qty": 1,
                    "product_price": 1.0,
                    "order_item_status": "Placed",
                    "feedback": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "payment_method_id": 2,
            "delivery_id": 2,
            "user_id": 2,
            "txnid": "",
            "order_no": "1-1583152785-0010",
            "order_total": 1.0,
            "payment_status": "Unpaid",
            "payuMoneyId": "",
            "mihpayid": "",
            "order_detail_data": [
                {
                    "order_detail_id": 2,
                    "order_id": 2,
                    "user_id": 2,
                    "qty": 1,
                    "product_price": 1.0,
                    "order_item_status": "Cancelled",
                    "feedback": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "order_id": 3,
            "payment_method_id": 1,
            "delivery_id": 2,
            "user_id": 1,
            "txnid": "83e066ca75437f433343d05b0",
            "order_no": "2-1583152964-0019",
            "order_total": 2.0,
            "payment_status": "Paid",
            "payuMoneyId": "306044826",
            "mihpayid": "9956136979",
            "order_detail_data": [
                {
                    "order_detail_id": 3,
                    "order_id": 3,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "qty": 2,
                    "product_price": 1.0,
                    "order_item_status": "Placed",
                    "feedback": ""
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    "user_data": [
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "role": 0,
            "created_by": 0,
            "group_in": 0,
            "name": "Deebaco",
            "email": "singh.deeba@gmail.com",
            "mobile": "",
            "password": "",
            "image": "",
            "last_login": null,
            "rand": "",
            "opened": 0,
            "auth_id": "114025425174039",
            "auth_platform": "Google",
            "created_datetime": "2020-03-02T17:54:28",
            "updated_datetime": "2020-03-02T17:54:28",
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "user_id": 2,
            "role": 0,
            "created_by": 0,
            "group_in": 0,
            "name": "Kriti Mathur",
            "email": "mathurkriti@gmail.com",
            "mobile": "",
            "password": "",
            "image": "",
            "last_login": null,
            "rand": "",
            "opened": 0,
            "auth_id": "111445960345755",
            "auth_platform": "Google",
            "created_datetime": "2020-03-02T18:02:24",
            "updated_datetime": "2020-03-02T18:02:24",
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "user_id": 3,
            "role": 0,
            "created_by": 0,
            "group_in": 0,
            "name": "Sakshi Swarnkar",
            "email": "sakshi@gmail.com",
            "mobile": "",
            "password": "",
            "image": "",
            "last_login": null,
            "rand": "",
            "opened": 0,
            "auth_id": "117543975857",
            "auth_platform": "Google",
            "created_datetime": "2020-03-02T18:02:24",
            "updated_datetime": "2020-03-02T18:02:24",
            "status": "Active"
        },
    ]
}
```

**what i want is like this below**: get name replace of user_id.

```
{
    "order_data": [
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "payment_method_id": 1,
            "delivery_id": 2,
            "name": "Sakshi Swarnkar",
            "txnid": "584ffb7fd622eca10a6d",
            "order_no": "1-1583152683-0005",
            "order_total": 1.0,
            "payment_status": "Paid",
            "payuMoneyId": "306043618",
            "mihpayid": "9956109007",
            "order_detail_data": [
                {
                    "order_detail_id": 1,
                    "order_id": 1,
                    "name": "Sakshi Swarnkar",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "product_price": 1.0,
                    "order_item_status": "Placed",
                    "feedback": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "payment_method_id": 2,
            "delivery_id": 2,
            "name": "Kriti Mathur",
            "txnid": "",
            "order_no": "1-1583152785-0010",
            "order_total": 1.0,
            "payment_status": "Unpaid",
            "payuMoneyId": "",
            "mihpayid": "",
            "order_detail_data": [
                {
                    "order_detail_id": 2,
                    "order_id": 2,
                    "name": "Kriti Mathur",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "product_price": 1.0,
                    "order_item_status": "Cancelled",
                    "feedback": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "order_id": 3,
            "payment_method_id": 1,
            "delivery_id": 2,
            "name": "Deebaco",
            "txnid": "83e066ca75437f433343d05b0",
            "order_no": "2-1583152964-0019",
            "order_total": 2.0,
            "payment_status": "Paid",
            "payuMoneyId": "306044826",
            "mihpayid": "9956136979",
            "order_detail_data": [
                {
                    "order_detail_id": 3,
                    "order_id": 3,
                    "name": "Deebaco",
                    "qty": 2,
                    "product_price": 1.0,
                    "order_item_status": "Placed",
                    "feedback": ""
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
```

> i am direct fetching data using raw query from databases instead of
>   ORM. i want to get user-name replace of user_id.

i am trying to solve this problem, but i didn't get any possible answer which could solve this problem. It would be great if anyone could help me out for what i am looking for. Advance thank you so much!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the sql query of: `order_query = ''' SELECT * FROM orders '''`

Your sql query will need a join

```
SELECT users.name,order.* from order left join users on order.user_id = users.user_id
```

It will not be exactly what you expect because I don't have all the information and I'm making assumptions about your DB, but this should work after you reworked it slightly

Comment: okay thanks! how to set pagination as per page?

Comment: I assume you are using django REST framework - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#limitoffsetpagination

Comment: that's does not work, can you make a custom pagination in this code?

Comment: Please ask this in a separate question

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540700/django-how-to-set-pagination)

Comment: do you have solving result for this above link?