# Django: how to set pagination in resfulapi?

Tags: python, sql, django, api, django-pagination

here i tried django default pagination in my views, query works perfectly but pagination does not work for me.  what should i do? i guess i have to make a custom pagination as per my code. it would be great if anybody could help me where i made mistake in my code.

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
class DefaultResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 100000

class Order_ListAPIView(APIView):
    pagination_class = DefaultResultsSetPagination
    def get(self,request,format=None):

        if request.method == 'GET':
            cur,conn = connection()
            order_query = ''' SELECT * FROM orders'''
            order_detail_query = ''' SELECT * FROM order_details'''


            ...
             ... #rest_code
              ...


            return Response({"order_data":order_data},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 2
}
```

Comment: describe what `not working` for you, any errors ?

Comment: i set djangorestapi default pagination in my code but pagination doesn't work for me.

Comment: in your url if you add extra ?page=1 what s happen?

Comment: nothing happen, it's still remain same. @Florin

Comment: but your query its working?

Comment: yes it's working perfect! do you have other solution how to set pagination in query as per page? @Florin

Comment: paginator = DefaultResultsSetPagination()
result  = paginator.paginate_queryset(order_query, request)

I couldn't check whether this is a workaround.